Linear warmup always result in a significant drop in accuracy
I'm at a machine learning task where I used linear warmup for a machine learning task. However, I observed that the test accuracy always drops significantly after the warmup, sometimes even during warmup. For example, in the image below. I'm using warmup for the first 5 epochs (0-4 steps). And after the warmup, when the learning rate starts to become constant. In the 6 epoch, the accuracy drops significantly. I tried using cosine anneal, but the same thing happened. Sometimes, the accuracy even began to drop significantly during the warmup, for example, in the 4th or 5th epoch. Does anyone know if this is normal, or what could be wrong? Any help is appreciated.
Sorry, I didn't provide enough information earlier. I'm using the adam operator and also the weight decay. The training size consists of 40 batches of sequences, typically the sequence length is around 2000, and the input dimension is 2048. The test set consists of 32 batches of similar sequences, also with around 2000 seq length and 2048 input dimension. The curve is the test accuracy that I monitor. I also uploaded the loss curve here, I used CE loss in this case. You can see the loss went up a bit in the 6th epoch (from 0.027 to 0.031). Let me know if further information is needed

Thanks for replying to me. I just edited the question so that it contains the information you needed

Thanks for the helpful additions. What type of model, e.g. is it a recurrent one like an LSTM, or convolutional, or something else? For the 40 batches, typically how many samples/sequences per batch?

The model is a recurrent one, with 6 layers. For each batch, it typically consists of a sequence of inputs. Seq length is typically around 2000, input dimension is 2048. So, the input shape is (B,L,H), which is (1, 2000,2048). The data is actually 40 videos, downsampled into pictures. The data is fed into the model video by video, which means each video is a batch that contains one sequence of input vector.

As you've pointed out, the train loss goes up at the same time the validation loss drops. To me, this suggests that the learning rate increase has led to an instability, as the model momentarily fails on the training data.
If it's happening both during and after warmup, it could be that the increase is too rapid during warmup, and the final value is too large for stable behaviour.
I might try to replace the scheduled $lr$ with a single lower constant $lr$ for the entirety of training, and observe if the model exhibits the same instability.
As a side-note, a sequence length of 2000 sounds like a lot to me for a recurrent model - LSTMs typically manage up to a few hundred time steps? That might also contribute to irregularities in training by virtue of unstable gradients.
I think a 1D convolutional net would handle the long sequences more effectively. You could also take a hybrid approach where 1D conv layers compress the sequence length, followed by LSTMs on those compressed sequences, but I'd just stick with a convolutional architecture for initial testing.
If I understood correctly, the data is arranged into 40 samples. This is a relatively small number compared to the model size (6-layer LSTM with 2048 input features). Using weight decay, as you're doing, will help mitigate overfitting, but if you find the model isn't scoring highly enough, then a simpler one might work better.
Since the data is spatio-temporal, incorporating 2D convolutions could help with performance.

Thanks! These are extremely helpful!

My pleasure @WillWu, glad I could help.
